Why is the C-Cl bond length in 4-chlorobenzaldehyde shorter than in chlorobenzene?
I understand that the -COH group in 4-chlorobenzaldehyde withdraws electron density from the benzene ring via the mesomeric (resonance) effect. This should, theoretically, reduce the electron density in the ring. However, I am confused about how this affects the interaction between the chlorine substituent and the benzene ring.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain it.

You tried it on your own?

It would help the question if you could quote some appropriate values, and provide references to where you found them

Due to the -R effect of -CHO the electron density in the ring reduces which allows chlorine to donate its electrons much easier. This would lead to an increased double bond character as compared to chlorobenzene where there is no electron withdrawing group.

Sir, does the relative position of the -COH group with respect to the chlorine group affect this? I think not, because the -COH group will always draw electron density from the benzene ring, making it easier for the chlorine to donate its electrons. Am I correct?

The position does matter. The -R effect of -CHO will create a reduced electron density at ortho and para positions not meta. If there was a -CHO at meta position relative to the Cl, we would only consider -I effect of CHO which doesnt cause much of a difference as compared to the -R effect
